# Buttons inside list item don't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 2 views: PollCard and PollList (like list of polls) 
In the PollCard view I have 2 buttons(images), that calls "answer" function:

```swift
HStack{
    Button(action: {
        self.answer()
        print("Pressed first image")
    }){
        Image(poll.v1img)
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
    }.frame(width: 150, height: 200)
    Button(action: {  self.answer()}){
        Image(poll.v2img )
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
    }.frame(width: 150, height: 200).zIndex(4)
}
```

In the `PollList` view I have this simple list:

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        List(pollData) { poll in
            PollCard(poll: poll)
            }.padding()
    }
}
```

But when I click the images in the list, it selects like all images and presses it
[image: Example]

It is also very easy to check - terminal prints `Pressed first image` even if I've pressed only second image

**What should I do to fix this?**

Comment: I was able to reproduce this...If you replace the `HStack` around your `List` with a `ScrollView` and the `List` with a `ForEach` it woks. I think this happens because `List` is designed as a container for one column and with your `HStack` inside your `List` you create 2 columns.

Comment: @krjw List or ScrollView, both could contain ForEach container ... The trouble is with the Button self. Replacing List with ScrollView is not the best idea ... Still the workaround exist /see my answer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section the workaround would be to substitute the `HStack` around the `List` with a `ScrollView` and the `List` with a `ForEach`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    struct Data: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
    }

    @State var data = [Data(id: 0), Data(id: 1), Data(id: 2), Data(id: 3), Data(id: 4), Data(id: 5)]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(self.data) { data in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Pressed blue...")
                    }, label: {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Pressed red...")
                    }, label: {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this is an unexpected behavior of Button (or it is a bug?) in current SwiftUI (either on macOS or iOS).

The workaround in your case is simple, try to apply PlainButtonStyle for your buttons

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("button1")
                }) {
                    Color.yellow
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    print("button2")
                }) {
                    Color.green
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that it is enough to apply the style on one button only ... or apply it to parent HStack :-)

changing ContentView ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello, World!")

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("button1")
                }) {
                    Color.yellow
                }

                Button(action: {
                    print("button2")
                }) {
                    Color.green
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .frame(height: 100)

            Text("By by, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

you get
[image]

where each of buttons works as expected